# Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules ( Read And Write )

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Ok I have a Realtime database connected to a app and till today the rules ( read and write ) were set to true  , everything was working fine ....but every time a message pops up saying

> Your security rules are defined as public, so anyone can steal, modify, or delete data in your database

I tried few things but data was not accessed...data was only accessible when the rules were set to true

*but is there any way to modify the rules to make it more secure*

**I want this Data to be accessed by only few known apps ( My Apps )**

Comment: There's no way for us to help with the question in its current form. I recommend adding focus on specifically what you tried, and reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (again if needed), as following the guidance in there drastically increases the chance that someone here can help.

Comment: Okkk... So unless someone has access to my Google account or a app /web integrated with my database... No one can access the data even if the rules are set to true, am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start [here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) and work your way through. It's very practical and easy to understand.

> data was only accessible when the rules were set to true

Firebase RTDB has a public URL, so anyone can try connecting to it. It is your job to decide whether they can do this or not. If your rules for any path/node look like this, it is available to anyone who makes a request:

```js
{
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
}
```

If you only want to allow users of your app to connect to RTDB, you can use Firebase Auth and use conditions like this:

```js
{
  ".read": "auth != null"
  ".write": "auth != null"
}
```

> I want this Data to be accessed by only few known apps ( My Apps )

Access is determined on a user level, not by app. Start [here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/get-started#set_up).

> but is there any way to modify the rules to make it more secure

Either in the Firebase Console, or deploy them via the CLI. If you're new to this, start with the Firebase Console and use the Rules Playground to test different rules. [See docs for more information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy).

> So unless someone has access to my Google account or a app /web integrated with my database... No one can access the data even if the rules are set to true, am I right ?

Your database is not "integrated". It is a deployed instance that is reachable via a public URL - that's how your clients connect to RTDB. If your rules allow *any* read or write operation, then your database is wide and open for everyone. Hence, the email that you have received informing you that this is not secure.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
   ".write": "auth.uid !== null"
  }
}
```

Currently accepted Rule [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics?authuser=0&hl=en#realtime-database_1)